# Using "kubectl delete pods X" from inside Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, eventstoredb

We're using a >1.8 version of k8s on gcloud. Unfortunately EventStore stops pushing data until it is rebooted. Thus we'd like to run `kubectl --namespace=$NAMESPACE delete pod eventstore-0` every 6 hours. Thus we have a cron job like:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: eventstore-restart
spec:
  # Run every full hour, 15 past, 30 past, 45 past every other time-unit.
  schedule: "0,15,30,45 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: eventstore-restart
            image: eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/kubectl:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]
            args:
            - 'set -x; kubectl --namespace=$NAMESPACE get pods
               | grep -ho "eventstore-\d+"
               | xargs -n 1 -I {} kubectl --namespace=$NAMESPACE delete pod {}'
            env:
            - name: NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          serviceAccount: restart-eventstore
```

However, this seems to expand to `kubectl get pods ...`, piped with `| { ... }`, which causes `"/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "}")` to fail the script.

**How do I write the command to delete a pod on a schedule**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
kubectl delete po $(kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | grep eventstore) -n $NAMESPACE
```

or (your way)

```
kubectl get pods -n $NAMESPACE -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | grep eventstore | xargs -n 1 -I {} kubectl delete po {}
```

Now, if you know you want to delete pod "eventstore-0", why to not do directly `kubectl delete pod eventstore-0`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use label selectors to filter results of `kubectl get`, and jsonpath output to get just the name of the pod.

Assuming that your pod is labeled with `app=eventstore` and that you want to delete every pod with this label, you could use the following command:

```
k get po --namespace=$NAMESPACE --selector app=eventstore -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.name}" | xargs -n 1 -I {} kubectl --namespace=$NAMESPACE delete po {}
```

If you want to delete just the first pod, use `jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}"`

Comment: Thank you for the help; both yours and suren's suggestions would work, but we went for `            command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]
            args:
            - 'set -x; kubectl --namespace=$NAMESPACE delete pod eventstore-0'` in the end; which is more similar to his answer.

Comment: Haha no worries

Answer (score 0):

@suren answer is good, but it won't work in all the cases when you want to delete multiple **specific** pods. For example, if you have: pod1, pod2, pod3, pod4, and you want to delete only pod2 and pod4, you can't do it with grep (`grep pod` will catch all of them).

In that case, you can delete them like that:

```
kubectl delete pods -n $NAMESPACE $(echo -e 'pod2\npod4')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it like this:

```
kubectl get pods -n your-namespace | grep eventstore | awk '{print $1,$2}' | xargs kubectl delete pod $2 -n $1
```

You can replace the word `eventstore` by some other search criteria in the grep command to fit your needs. You can also modify the `kubectl get` filters.